# Github:documents about github pages

Tags: github, blogs

Is there any document about the whole process of building my blog with github pages?I have read the official introduction,but less help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways to create a GitHub page:

- Create a repo called YOUR_USERNAME.github.io
- Create a branch called gh-pages on a standard repo

Later, you must put some HTML files and commit. You will see the page running. You can also use Jekyll which has a template engine but it's a bit hard to start with it.

Comment: yeah,i know that.while i push branch gh-pages,i found the link doesn't work.

Comment: The URL will be: http://USERNAME.github.io/PROJECT . If you find this difficult try the Automatic Page Generator. Go to your project settings and run the Automatic Page Generator. It's less customizable but it works.